Flattening nested data generated in a table
The data in the following is structured like this $\{\cdot,\{\cdot,\cdot\}\}$, but I need it like this $\{\cdot,\cdot,\cdot\}$. How do I do this?
termTwo[k_,α_,θ_,A_] := Sum[((1+A^2)Cos[m θ](Sin[(m k)/2])^2)/m^(1+α), {m, 1, 200}]
termOne[k_,θ_,α_,A_]:= Sum[((1+A^2)Cos[m θ](Sin[(m k)/2])^2-A^2 Cos[m θ])/m^(1+α), {m, 1, 200}]
data = Table[{A, FindArgMin[{termOne[k,θ,α,A] *termTwo[k,θ,α,A] /. 
       α -> 1, -Pi <= k <= Pi, -Pi <= θ <= Pi}, {θ,1},{k, 1}]}, {A, 0,1,0.05}]

I tried using a combination of First@, but that didn't work.

Flatten /@ data

Apply[Sequence]:
termTwo[k_, α_, θ_, A_] := 
 Sum[((1 + A^2) Cos[m θ] (Sin[(m k)/2])^2)/
   m^(1 + α), {m, 1, 200}]
termOne[k_, θ_, α_, A_] := 
 Sum[((1 + A^2) Cos[m θ] (Sin[(m k)/2])^2 - 
     A^2 Cos[m θ])/m^(1 + α), {m, 1, 200}]
data = Table[{A, 
   Sequence @@ 
    FindArgMin[{termOne[k, θ, α, A]*
        termTwo[k, θ, α, A] /. α -> 1, -Pi <= 
       k <= Pi, -Pi <= θ <= Pi}, {θ, 1}, {k, 1}]}, {A, 
   0, 1, 0.05}]


For versions after v12.1, you can use Splice@FindArgMin[...].
